# Wordpress Permalinks Broken after checking ModRewrite .htaccess and disabling plugins

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm facing a weird issue Permalink issue.

Wordpress pretty permalinks are broken and after disabling all plugins and adding the default Wordpress .htaccess file I still can't get them to work.

I've verified .htaccess permissions and the Apache user can make changes to it when I change Permalink settings in Wordpress. I've switched between permalinks several times from plain numeric to more pretty variants. The only thing that works is the numeric links.

I'm hosting Wordpress on DirectAdmin and there are several other installs of Wordpress on the same Webserver that work perfectly well. Apache Rewrite is enabled on this server.

Does anyone have other Ideas where I can dig?

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo a2enmod rewrite
2. then follow instructions: "What I found is the apache2.conf file did not have the AllowOveride directive set to ‘All’. It was set to ‘None’ which overlooks all .htaccess files. once I set that and restarted Apache then the .htaccess file was being read and the rewrite rules all work now."
3. sudo systemctl restart apache2